# Displaying "Requires Android" for the App in Google Play store

Tags: android

I have released my App to Google Play store and it shows fine. But for this App in Additional info I do not see "Requires Android" version.

I have following version restriction defined in build.gradle and users with their Android version below 5 / sdk 28 are not able to install which is right but not sure why it is not showing up in additional info?

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 28
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        androidXCore = "1.5.0"
    }
```

[Here is the "Requires Android info not showing for my App. This is sample image from Google Play Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuQ6w.png)

Appreciate any help / pointers to fix this.

Thank you.

-Reds

Comment: The version restriction you are showing here in your gradle file is your app needs at least Android 9 (SDK 28), not sure where you are getting the idea that its Android 5

Comment: Sorry Android 9. Which settings makes Play store show this required android version info?